# Why does a hook state change cause component to render?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In an example app, in a function component:

```
const [searchApi, results, errorMessage] = useResults();
```

Further in the component, other components are rendered and they get passed the results/errorMessage. A textInput can also call the searchApi function on completion,

The corresponting useResults is declared inside useResults.js:

```
export default () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const searchApi = async searchTerm => {
//makes a request, depending on the success it either uses setResults or setErrorMessage
  };

  return [searchApi, results, errorMessage];
};
```

Now, if searchApi sets the state of the results or errorMessage inside the exported function itself, since I take it they may be considered as local variables, and the results and errorMessage inside the main component merely get the returned values before they even changed, then how come a change of state inside the function changes the variables outside of it? In other words, why does the component just re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as searchApi function calls either setResults or setErrorMessage, the react hook called will notify the component that contains the hook to re-render. That is also true when it comes to custom hooks that are using useState.

This behaviour makes sense, because as you said, results and errorMessage are some local variables that are not directly connected to the state. They are a snapshot of how the states looked like when the render function kicked in. If one of them changes, the only way the component will know about the change is by re-rendering (and getting the new values by calling the useState hook).